# WPF combo box seems to cause InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

Excerpt from [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ComboBox.cs):

```
private void CloneLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)SelectionBoxItem;
    rect.Width = _clonedElement.RenderSize.Width;
    rect.Height = _clonedElement.RenderSize.Height;

    VisualBrush visualBrush = (VisualBrush)rect.Fill; // (x)
    visualBrush.Viewbox = new Rect(_clonedElement.RenderSize);
    visualBrush.Viewport = new Rect(_clonedElement.RenderSize);
}
```

I would claim line (x) to be buggy since `rect.Fill` might refer to a `SolidColorBrush`.

Has someone (simple?) `Xaml` / `C#` code to throw the exception?

Comment: Could not understand the ask.  Is this code not working for you ?  What exception are you getting ? Can you please add details to the question.

Comment: Obviously, `rect.Brish` isn't a `VisualBrush`.

Comment: @ManojChoudhari: If `rect.Fill`is a `SolidColorBrush` and you try to cast it to a `VisualBrush` you'll get an `InvalidCastException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectionBoxItem` is a read only dependency property. The creation of its actual value is handled internal to the `ComboBox` class and no value for it could come externally. If you inspect `UpdateSelectionBoxItem` method right above, you will see that the handler in question is only registered when `SelectionBoxItem` is set to a `Rectangle` that has a `VisualBrush` as it’s `Fill`. Therefore these casts are “safe”, rect.Fill will never refer to anything other than a `VisualBrush` when that event handler is called.